# How to get Windows' Cumulative Update Version?

Tags: c#, windows

Is there an efficient and simple way to retrieve the version number of the last Windows Update using C# and .NET?
Specifically, this number (found using winver.exe):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

So people finding this are informed, this value is called 'Update Build Revision' - or UBR for short - and is found in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR
```

Comment: That question is about the windows release version, which is a different number than the one I need to find.

Comment: Did you look at that registry key mentioned in the accepted answer? Whatever version information you're looking for should be there or in Environment.OSVersion.

Comment: You're right, it's in the same registry key. Thanks.